# Writing an operator overload in C#, for a complex type, which relies on the operator itself

Tags: c#, null, operator-overloading, stack-overflow

I have a complex type called "HalfDay" which is a combination of a DateTime and an Enum value to represent either AM/PM.

```
public class HalfDay
{
  private DateTime _Date;
  public DateTime Date { get { return _Date; } set { _Date = value.Date; } }
  private DayHalf _Half;
  public DayHalf Half { get { return _Half; } set { _Half = value; } }
}
```

I am trying to write a set of overloaded operators to compare two HalfDays.

```
    public static bool operator <(HalfDay halfday1, HalfDay halfday2)
    {
        if (halfday1.Date.Date < halfday2.Date.Date) return true;
        if (halfday1.Date == halfday2.Date && halfday1.Half < halfday2.Half) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator >(HalfDay halfday1, HalfDay halfday2)
    {
        if (halfday1.Date.Date > halfday2.Date.Date) return true;
        if (halfday1.Date == halfday2.Date && halfday1.Half > halfday2.Half) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(HalfDay halfday1, HalfDay halfday2)
    {
        if (halfday1 == null && halfday2 == null) return true;
        if (halfday1 == null || halfday2 == null) return false;

        return halfday1.Date.Date == halfday2.Date.Date && halfday1.Half == halfday2.Half;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(HalfDay halfday1, HalfDay halfday2)
    {
        if (halfday1 == null && halfday2 == null) return false;
        if (halfday1 == null || halfday2 == null) return true;

        return !(halfday1 == halfday2);
    }
```

In true newbie style (I've never written operators before) I've used the == comparison to compare a HalfDay with null. The result is, of course, a stack overflow as my operator code gets called recursively.

I think I need to check for null in my operators to correctly return false (or true) for comparisons being made where either of the arguments is null. I've clearly misunderstood something fundamental about OOP though - any pointers on how I should correctly write these operators?

Comment: Any reason why you're not use auto-properties?

Comment: @svick I can't remember why as I wrote it a small while ago, but something to do with EF Code First and persistence. I think, once upon a time, I wanted the properties to only have getters and have some clever logic for adding halfdays on (for use in Enumerable.Range) - it could be a code smell now though, I'll investigate! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already mentioned, when you want to check for reference equality, bypassing any `==` or `Equals()`, use [`object.ReferenceEquals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals).

Also, when overloading `==`, you should also override `Equals()` (and implement `IEquatable<T>`). When you do that, you can then take advantage of the fact that `object.Equals(object, object)` makes all the null checks and then invokes `Equals()`. So, your code could look like this:

```
public bool Equals(HalfDay other)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        return false;
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, this))
        return true;

   return this.Date.Date == other.Date.Date && this.Half == other.Half;
}

public int GetHashCode()
{
    // TODO
}

public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    return Equals(other as HalfDay);
}

public static bool operator ==(HalfDay halfday1, HalfDay halfday2)
{
    return object.Equals(halfday1, halfday2);
}

public static bool operator !=(HalfDay halfday1, HalfDay halfday2)
{
    return !(halfday1 == halfday2);
}
```

Also, keep in mind what happens when there is a type that inherits from `HalfDay`. If you don't want to deal with that, make `HalfDay` `sealed`.

But, considering that you're also implementing comparison operators, you should considering unifying those too. For an example (with detailed explanation), see [Eric Lippert's *Math from scratch, part six: comparisons*](http://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/) (you don't need to read the rest of the series).

Comment: Given that HalfDay was originally supposed to be a POCO for EF Code First, what effect would implementing IEquatable<T> have on the class? I've tried to use simple data types through my POCOs where possible, but I was getting annoyed with rewriting the same code over and over to compare two HalfDays, hence why I looked into operator overloads. Is it "acceptable" to add these overloads and overrides to POCOs? I appreciate that might not be a black and white answer.

Comment: @DanielArkley The way I understand it, [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) means “an object that's not tied to your ORM in any way”. It doesn't mean you can't implement interfaces or overload operators on it.

Comment: Fair enough :) Implemented all of that. For GetHashCode, I used:
`public int GetHashCode()
    {
      return new { Date = Date, Half = Half }.GetHashCode();
    }`

Answer (score 2):

See: [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> A common error in overloads of operator == is to use (a == b), (a ==
>   null), or (b == null) to check for reference equality. This instead
>   results in a call to the overloaded operator ==, causing an infinite
>   loop. Use ReferenceEquals or cast the type to Object, to avoid the
>   loop.

For comparing it against `null` you can do *(Example code from documentation)*:

```
// If one is null, but not both, return false.
if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
{
    return false;
}
```

Also read:

By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by determining if two references indicate the same object, so reference types do not need to implement operator == in order to gain this functionality. When a type is immutable, meaning the data contained in the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator == to compare value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they have the same value. **Overriding operator == in non-immutable types is not recommended.**

Comment: @Habib If overriding == isn't recommended, what other options do I have. Should I be overriding Equals() instead?

Comment: @DanielArkley, since your class is mutable, its better if you override `Equals` instead of `==` operator.

Comment: @DanielArkley Be careful about terminology. You don't override `==`, you *overload* it. On the other hand, you do override `object.Equals(object)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
public static bool operator ==(HalfDay halfday1, HalfDay halfday2)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(halfday1, halfday2)) return true;
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(halfday1, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(halfday2, null)) return false;

    return halfday1.Date.Date == halfday2.Date.Date && halfday1.Half == halfday2.Half;
}
```